pgsql similar plan but different execution time
I have a product_demand view which is an aggregation of 4 tables. Each table will have a generated column type VARCHAR with same static value for all rows of same table. An index is created on (type, row_id) to enhance query.
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW product_demand
AS
SELECT ol.type,
       ol.row_id,
       o.order_date,
       ol.warehouse_code_source AS warehouse_code,
       ol.product_code,
       ol.product_price,
       ol.ordered_quantity,
       ol.ordered_value,
       ol.status_id,
       ol.active,
       ol.last_modified_at,
       ol.last_modified_by,
       ol.created_at,
       ol.created_by
FROM customer_order_line ol
         JOIN customer_order o
              ON ol.order_code = o.code
UNION ALL
SELECT ol.type,
       ol.row_id,
       o.order_date,
       ol.warehouse_code,
       ol.product_code,
       ol.product_price,
       ol.ordered_quantity,
       ol.ordered_value,
       ol.status_id,
       ol.active,
       ol.last_modified_at,
       ol.last_modified_by,
       ol.created_at,
       ol.created_by
FROM fabrication_order_line ol
         JOIN fabrication_order o
              ON ol.order_code = o.code
                  AND ol.warehouse_code = o.warehouse_code
                  AND ol.kit_code = o.kit_code
UNION ALL
SELECT ol.type,
       ol.row_id,
       o.order_date,
       ol.warehouse_code_destination AS warehouse_code,
       ol.product_code,
       ol.product_price,
       ol.ordered_quantity,
       ol.ordered_value,
       ol.status_id,
       ol.active,
       ol.last_modified_at,
       ol.last_modified_by,
       ol.created_at,
       ol.created_by
FROM distribution_order_line ol
         JOIN distribution_order o
              ON ol.order_code = o.code
UNION ALL
SELECT ol.type,
       ol.row_id,
       o.order_date,
       ol.warehouse_code_destination AS warehouse_code,
       ol.product_code,
       ol.product_price,
       ol.ordered_quantity,
       ol.ordered_value,
       ol.status_id,
       ol.active,
       ol.last_modified_at,
       ol.last_modified_by,
       ol.created_at,
       ol.created_by
FROM supplier_order_line ol
         JOIN supplier_order o
              ON ol.order_code = o.code;

When I do a typical query of rows in interval with certain type
SELECT warehouse_code,
       product_code,
       order_date,
       ordered_quantity,
       product_price,
       type
FROM product_demand pd
WHERE warehouse_code = 'Magasin 1'
  AND type = 'CUSTOMER'
  AND order_date >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND order_date <= '2024-01-01 00:00:00'

I get this plan (omitting non executed parts) https://explain.depesz.com/s/6b07
Append  (cost=0.72..732313.67 rows=1586548 width=45) (actual time=635.282..7059.162 rows=1441020 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=10837 read=100489
"  ->  Subquery Scan on ""*SELECT* 1""  (cost=0.72..724366.50 rows=1586545 width=45) (actual time=635.280..5643.339 rows=1441020 loops=1)"
        Buffers: shared hit=10837 read=100487
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..708501.05 rows=1586545 width=144) (actual time=635.275..4195.377 rows=1441020 loops=1)
              Buffers: shared hit=10837 read=100487
              ->  Index Scan using customer_order_pkey on customer_order o  (cost=0.29..767.48 rows=3656 width=19) (actual time=635.199..640.996 rows=3650 loops=1)
                    Filter: ((order_date >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (order_date <= '2024-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 10960
                    Buffers: shared hit=3 read=294
              ->  Index Scan using col_idx_order_code on customer_order_line ol  (cost=0.44..188.08 rows=550 width=48) (actual time=0.013..0.567 rows=395 loops=3650)
                    Index Cond: ((order_code)::text = (o.code)::text)
                    Filter: (((warehouse_code_source)::text = 'Magasin 1'::text) AND (type = 'CUSTOMER'::order_type))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1181
                    Buffers: shared hit=10834 read=100193
"  ->  Subquery Scan on ""*SELECT* 2""  (cost=0.00..0.03 rows=1 width=92) (actual time=0.010..0.013 rows=0 loops=1)"
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=191) (actual time=0.008..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
"  ->  Subquery Scan on ""*SELECT* 3""  (cost=0.00..0.02 rows=1 width=92) (actual time=0.005..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)"
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=191) (actual time=0.004..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
"  ->  Subquery Scan on ""*SELECT* 4""  (cost=0.58..14.38 rows=1 width=45) (actual time=0.032..0.035 rows=0 loops=1)"
        Buffers: shared read=2
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.58..14.37 rows=1 width=144) (actual time=0.031..0.032 rows=0 loops=1)
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=264 read=14
Planning Time: 3.393 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 46
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 6.095 ms, Inlining 133.553 ms, Optimization 295.222 ms, Emission 206.206 ms, Total 641.077 ms"
Execution Time: 7799.647 ms

However, when I inline the original table corresponding to the filter condition type = 'CUSTOMER' instead of the whole view
SELECT warehouse_code,
       product_code,
       order_date,
       ordered_quantity,
       product_price,
       type
FROM (
         SELECT ol.type,
                o.order_date,
                ol.warehouse_code_source AS warehouse_code,
                ol.product_code,
                ol.product_price,
                ol.ordered_quantity
         FROM customer_order_line ol
                  JOIN customer_order o
                       ON ol.order_code = o.code
         ) pd
WHERE warehouse_code = 'Magasin 1'
  AND type = 'CUSTOMER'
  AND order_date >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00'
  AND order_date <= '2024-01-01 00:00:00';

I get similar plan but with much less execution time https://explain.depesz.com/s/rhBN
Nested Loop  (cost=0.72..708501.05 rows=1586545 width=45) (actual time=192.386..3254.497 rows=1441020 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=111324
  ->  Index Scan using customer_order_pkey on customer_order o  (cost=0.29..767.48 rows=3656 width=19) (actual time=192.340..196.314 rows=3650 loops=1)
        Filter: ((order_date >= '2023-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone) AND (order_date <= '2024-01-01 00:00:00+00'::timestamp with time zone))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 10960
        Buffers: shared hit=297
  ->  Index Scan using col_idx_order_code on customer_order_line ol  (cost=0.44..188.08 rows=550 width=48) (actual time=0.007..0.435 rows=395 loops=3650)
        Index Cond: ((order_code)::text = (o.code)::text)
        Filter: (((warehouse_code_source)::text = 'Magasin 1'::text) AND (type = 'CUSTOMER'::order_type))
        Rows Removed by Filter: 1181
        Buffers: shared hit=111027
Planning:
  Buffers: shared hit=14
Planning Time: 0.486 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 10
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
"  Timing: Generation 0.878 ms, Inlining 22.027 ms, Optimization 127.451 ms, Emission 42.738 ms, Total 193.095 ms"
Execution Time: 3957.237 ms

Executing two queries multiple times does not decrease execution time further, so I'm curious as to why there is such disparity ?
I had tried VACUUM ANALYZE, increase some parameters such as max_worker_processes, max_parallel_workers and shared_buffers but no difference.

The subquery in the view seems to have a similar execution time. About 4 seconds. So the extra time must be coming from the view itself, which is the code that you omitted. Are you using UNION instead of UNION ALL to merge your 4 queries?

Thanks for the remark. The subquery took indeed similary exec time. The view uses UNION ALL so no distinct filtering. Furthermore, the total exec time of subqueries does not add up to the overall https://explain.depesz.com/s/6b07

This answer suggests it may be the instrumentation required by explain analyze itself that is adding the extra time. It says to try explain (analyze, timing off) and see what the overall timing of the query is. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165611/whats-actually-happening-in-the-result-node-and-append-in-a-postgres-plan

After adding timing off to both queries, the execution time is reduced in both case and come together very close (1,8s with view vs 1,2s with inline). Detail plans are https://explain.depesz.com/s/WRh9 and https://explain.depesz.com/s/St29

Please update the post with the full view's code. Omitting the query portion of the view makes it impossible to ascertain the reasons for the differences in execution time. You mentioned in a comment that the view includes a UNION ALL; however, the inlined version of the query doesn't. From this, it is obvious that the inlined portion is not the same as the view's query. With TIMING OFF, there is still a 33% performance penalty using the view vs. inline. Instead of posting the revised plans as links in a comment, update the original post with the plans as inline text.

If you insist. The inline version is where I put only the table corresponding to the filter condition type = 'CUSTOMER'. All other tables are ignored by a simple index check.
